# Automator in Mac | Schedule scripts with conda environment

Tags: macos, conda, environment, automator

I have some scripts that I want to schedule to run at a particular time period. For optimization purposes, I would want to run them inside a particular conda environment. However, I am unable to activate the environment inside the automator.

[image]

Comment: You have some Applescript which we can't see which and it runs a `bash` script which we can't see either.... what was the question?